# How to avoid breaking a loop due to an error in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm running a loop through a list of urls and some of the urls return the following error which breaks my loop and I'd like to avoid the break and just go to the next url in my list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\csv loop 2.py", line 28, in <module>
    price_clean = list(price_find.children)[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'
```

My idea was to introduce an `if` `else` statement to test the existence of a character in the url but this doesnt work and still returns the same error:

```
if soup.find("$") != -1:
    price_find = soup.find(class_="price")
    price_clean = list(price_find.children)[0]
else:
    continue
```

Any better ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: use *try except* https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: `soup.find` is not the same as `str.find`, but you could use `soup.text.find("$")`

Comment: This expression `soup.find("$") != -1` doesn't make sense, because a) `'$'` is not a tag, and b) `soup.find` retuens `Tag` objects or `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either check for `None` or catch the exception

**Checking for None**

```
if soup.find("$") != -1:
    price_find = soup.find(class_="price")
    if price_find is not None:
        price_clean = list(price_find.children)[0]
else:
    continue
```

**Catching the exception**

```
if soup.find("$") != -1:
    price_find = soup.find(class_="price")
    try:
        price_clean = list(price_find.children)[0]
    except AttributeError:
        pass
else:
    continue
```

And you will be able to carry on with the loop

Comment: Catching the exception solution worked! Thanks a lot!